# Timing C++ program on Mac

Tags: c++, macos

I want to time my threading program on my mac and knew that for Linux environments, you can time it by doing: "time ./a.out".

I tried this on my mac terminal and it seems to be working but gives a little different output. The one on Linux will give output in the format:
(random times btw)
real    0m0.792s
user    0m0.046s
sys     0m0.218s

while this one gives: ./a.out  0.84s user 1.49s system 29% cpu 7.866 total

What is the main difference between "real" and "user" and is there any other types of commands to time the execution of programs?

Comment: _"is there any type of command to time the execution of programs?"_ I don't follow... you just showed us one?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Typo, meant to say other type of commands*. Fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is well explained in the man pages, in both Linux and macOS.

**Linux**

> These statistics consist of (i) the elapsed **real time between invocation and termination**, (ii) the user CPU time and (iii) the system CPU time.

**macOS**

> time writes the total time elapsed, the time consumed by system
> overhead, and the time used to execute utility to the standard error
> stream.

- **Real** means the total time needed to execute the whole program, including startup and exit.
- **User** is basically your own code.
- **System** is the time spent calling system functions.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is not between "real" and "user"; the numbers are also in a different order.

The difference is between "real" and "total", and there isn't one. They're just different ways of saying the same thing: total, wall-clock, real-world time to execute your program, including all user code, system calls and (crucially) any time that your CPU spent on other processes/tasks.